# Как устно решить элементарную задачу с логическим выражением на делимость чисел

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Добрый день. Есть функция *D(n, m)*, проверяющая, кратно ли натуральное число *n* натуральному числу *m* (пишу на C++ 11):

```
bool D(int n, int m) {
    return n % m == 0;
}
```

Так же есть функция *F(A)*, которая сообщает о том, истинно ли некоторое выражение ***F*** при заданном натуральном значении *A* при натуральном *0 < x < 10000*:

```
bool F(int A) {
    for (int x = 1; x < 10000; x++) {
        bool F = !D(x, A) || D(x, 21) || D(x, 35); // некоторое выражение
        if (!F) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

В задаче дано выражение ***F*** и требуется найти либо минимальное, либо максимальное натуральное значение числа *A*, при котором данное выражение будет истинно при любом натуральном значении переменной *x*. Задачу программным способом я решил. ***Как решать такую задачу при помощи ручки и листка бумаги?*** Очень прошу помощи, нужно научиться решать такую задачу устно. Потратил 2 месяца впустую.

---

Вот пример некоторых задач:

**№1.** `bool F = !(D(x, 6) && !D(x, 4)) || (!D(x, 4) && D(x, A));` Найти наименьшее натуральное число A. Ответ: 1.

**№2.** `bool F = D(x, A) || (!D(x, 21) && !D(x, 35))` Найти наибольшее натуральное число A. Ответ: 7.

**№3.** `bool F = !D(x, 18) || D(x, A) || !D(x, 12)` Найти наибольшее натуральное число A. Ответ: 36.

**№4.** `bool F = !D(x, A) || !D(x, 21) || D(x, 35)` Найти наименьшее натуральное число A. Ответ: 5.

**№5.** `bool F = !(D(x, 456) && !D(x, 123)) || (!D(x, 123) && !D(x, A))` Найти наименьшее натуральное число A. Это шок, решать такую задачу на бумажке..

Comment: Может, задачу можно решить как-то математически? Нужен определённый метод, работающий для любых чисел, выражений. Находить делители чисел, использовать числовую прямую, круги эйлера - не помогает..

Comment: Ну тут наверное стоит начать с построения таблицы истинности для результирующей функции. И вывести из нее условие для блока с `A`.